# Find the limit of $x_n=\dfrac{1}{2n}\cos(n^3)-\dfrac{3n}{6n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Find the limit of $x_n=\dfrac{1}{2n}\cos(n^3)-\dfrac{3n}{6n+1}$.

My solution goes like this:

$x_n=\frac{1}{2n}\cos(n^3)-\frac{3n}{6n+1}\leq \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{3n}{6n+1}$. Now, we can easily verify that, $\exists N(\epsilon)\in \mathbb {N}$ such that $\forall n>N(\epsilon)$ we have, $|\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{3n}{6n+1}+\frac{1}{2}|<\epsilon $, $\forall \epsilon >0$. Hence, $x_n+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2n}\cos(n^3)-\frac{3n}{6n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\leq \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{3n}{6n+1}+\frac{1}{2}<\epsilon$, $\forall n>N(\epsilon)$. But, this should have been valid for $|x_n+1/2|$. But we cant say whether ,$|x_n+1/2|<\epsilon$, to conclude, $\lim x_n=-1/2$? How to do this? I am not quite getting this ...

Comment: Pick $N(\varepsilon)$ such that $|\frac{\cos(n^3)}{2n}| < \varepsilon/2$ and $|-\frac{3n}{6n + 1} + 1/2| < \varepsilon/2$ then use triangle inequality to show that $|x_n + 1/2| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Thanks! I do get it now...

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $f$ is bounded (at least around the limit point) and $g$ is infinitesimal, then
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)g(x) = 0
$$
Applying this to
$$
\cos(n^3)\frac{1}{2n}
$$
it goes to $0$, and the limit is determined by the other term and it is easily found as $-3/6 = -1/2$